# Failed creating virtual environment in python 3.7

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, pipenv

I tried to install virtual environment using `pipenv install` in **Python 3.7**,
but it is showing error.

```
Pipfile: C:\Users\jaisai\Desktop\myProject\Pipfile
Using C:/Users/jaisai/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe (3.7.0) to create virtualenv...
[   =] Creating virtual environment...FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\jaisai\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\Lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe'

Failed creating virtual environment

[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

**However, there was no issue in Python 3.9**

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: i just did pipenv install in python ver 3.6.0 so the error is  not about version...in your error it is mentioned that the required file want found and that is what creating this error for you

Comment: @SachinRajput Actually, there was some issue with Python 3.7, and a file was missing. However, in the latest version of Python 3.7 (ie, Python 3.7.9) the problem was fixed and there was no issue.

Comment: this is a bug in conda -- you can read more about it here (as well as workarounds): https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10822